# Django inlineformset how to not show id

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

So, I am working with inlineformset_factory and to properly receive all the fields in the post request, I am rendering all fields in the form (and not just the visible fields):

```
{% for field in form %}
<div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-form-label">{{field.label}}</div>
        {% if field.name == "id" or field.name == "user" %}

            <!-- What to do to not show id and user. -->

        {% else %}

            {{field|add_class:"form-control w-100"}}
        {% endif %}


</div>
{% endfor %}
```

So, what do I do to not show the id and user field labels?  It seems like even if I try to skip these labels, they still show.

Comment: The docs on [looping over hidden and visible fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#looping-over-hidden-and-visible-fields) might help. Note that hiding the `user` field does not stop the user from changing the value.

Answer (score 0):

Its because your label code `<div class="col-form-label">{{field.label}}</div>` is outside of `if` condition. You can try this code instead:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {% if field.name != "id" and field.name != "user" %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-form-label">{{field.label}}</div>
            {{field|add_class:"form-control w-100"}}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```